# Fast Ethernet UDP optimize receive buffers

Tags: linux, ethernet, udp, sysctl

I have a Linux computer which must receive streaming data from several devices (up to 30 or so) during long terms.

This computer is connected to a Fast Ethernet local area network (100 Mbps) where other devices are also connected, which means it is not dedicated.

As the streaming data is received via RTP (UDP), I have noticed that some of the packets are lost: maybe due to the switches/routers, maybe due to the current Linux OS.

In my tests I would like to **optimize Linux UDP buffers** so as to manage the high incoming data traffic rate, which sometimes could be higher than 50 Mbps.

Is this possible? Which parameter is more critical in this case? I have set several parameters in /etc/sysctl.conf but they may be wrong...so any help is highly appreciated.

I attach an example for this file. The computer has a **2 GB RAM** card.

Thanks in advance,

```
#The maximum socket receive buffer size which may be set by using the SO_RCVBUF socket option: 8 MB
net.core.rmem_max = 8388608
#The maximum socket send buffer size which may be set by using the SO_SNDBUF socket option: 512 KB
net.core.wmem_max = 524288

#The default setting in bytes of the socket receive buffer: 4 MB 
net.core.rmem_default = 4194304
#The default setting in bytes of the socket send buffer: 256 KB
net.core.wmem_default = 262144

# Increase the maximum amount of option memory buffers
net.core.optmem_max = 40960

# Increase the maximum total buffer-space allocatable
# This is measured in units of pages (4096 bytes)
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 262144
 net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 262144

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 8192 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384

# Disable TCP slow start on idle connections
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0

# If your servers talk UDP, also up these limits
#This is a vector of three integers governing the number of pages allowed for queueing by all UDP sockets. man 7 udp
net.ipv4.udp = 131072   196608  262144
#Minimal size, in bytes, of receive buffers used by UDP sockets in moderation.
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 1073741824

# Increase number of incoming connections backlog
#net.core.netdev_max_backlog=2048
```

Comment: You are aware that you work under the wrong assumption that 100mbit is a lot of data for a computer to handle? I would be surprised if any optimization would be seful for some that low data throughput. THis is 2015 - most networks today are a lot faster and no tuning is needed.

Comment: Spend $10 on a gigabit NIC.

Comment: Hello, I forgot to mention that the device is connected to the network through a M12-D connector, which imposes the 100 Mbps. The NIC could switch to Gigagbit Ethernet and the application could work correctly, but in this case it is impossible.

Comment: The buffers are very unlikely to be a significant part of the issue. It's much more likely to be other parts of the network and the software.

Comment: Is maybe UDP which introduces inherent losses over 50 Mbps? Above this rate the losses increase...

Comment: Increasing the buffers may help a little. I have made several tests including some port mirroring. Over 37 Mbps some packets could be lost... I think it is due to some kind of collisions which I have not been able to detect neither in the switch nor in the final device with tcpdump and gulp. Any other ideas?